# Passing Default Value into SSRS Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In SSRS I have a report parameter that is a multi-select and has a default label of (None) and default value of 0.

In my query I want to set it up so that I can pass in 0 or some other value(s). However, if I pass in 0, I don't want it to filter down the data.

Normally you would add the below clause to your where statement, but I'm not sure if or how this is done with multiple values.

(@Parameter = 0 OR table.column = @Parameter)

Comment: What I am trying is (0 in (@Parameter) OR table.Column in (@Parameter)) which seems to work but it is very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if I understand the question, you're going to pass a LIST OF POSIBLE VALUES or 0, right?...

If so, maybe the only change you have to do is set your parameter to string ('0' or '1,2,3') and do a condition like this

```
(@Parameter = '0' OR table.column IN (@Parameter))
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Now that i see what i wrote I think it might not work as it is, but if you pass a string with the values you want with some characters at the beging and end ( `'#1#2#3#'` for example ) and use the charindex function in the condition `(@Parameter = '0' OR charIndex('#'+table.column+'#', @Parameter) > 0)` it might work

Comment: I see you have problems with the performance this can be because of the IN if you are sending a lot of 'posibilities', don't know if this can be done in SSRS but when I have cases like this is better to create a temp table with one column, insert the values of the parameter in the table and instead of the condition add a left join with this temp table and filter `AND #tmp.column IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling a procedure or running a direct query from SSRS?

If you're calling a proc you could try determining in the proc whether any filtering needs to take place, something like

```
DECLARE @filter INT
SELECT @filter = LEN(@parameter)
-- or something similar to determine if there are any parameters

SELECT
   -- everything you want
WHERE
    @filter = 0 OR table.Column IN (@parameter)
```

Comment: Then change to run a procedure, it's more maintainable and flexible.

Comment: That is what I would prefer to do, but I can't because I have read only access to the database, which is stupid.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am testing the query in SQL itself and it is running slow, so it is even slower in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the parameters exactly as the user fills them in onto the queries.

On your dataset you can have 2 parameters:
`@Parameters` and `@ApplyFilter`

and then on the Parameters tab of the dataset (Parameter Name = Parameter Value):

```
@Parameters = @Parameters
@ApplyFilter = IIF(And(Parameters!Parameters.Value.Length = 1,Parameters!Parameters.Value(0)=0),"0","1")
```

Finally your SQL Filter would need to be something like:

```
WHERE
   (@ApplyFilter = 1 AND tbl.column IN (@Parameters))
```

The reason why I prefer this solution is because you make the query more readable!